# Auto Update of Pmf from a specific mxd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-publisher

I currently have two file folders with a mxd in each of the folder. These two file structures and mxd name will be kept constant. Once a week or month, I will update these two mxd. Then, I will generate a couple of pmf (with data package) from these mxd, and save them into a another folder (fixed location).

Is there a way I can generate pmf with data package automatically (update interval set to once a week / month)?

Im on 9.3.1 Desktop, Server license, with Publisher. Sorry to say this but I do not have knowledge of scripts/python.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed previously on the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53195-Publish-MXD-files-to-PMF-in-Batch)** where an Esri employee said:

> ArcMap currently there is no option to do this, arcpy doesn’t have
>   access to the publisher extension which is required for creating a pmf
>   from a mxd.

He suggests voting for the ArcGIS Idea to provide **[Python access to Publisher Extension!](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004mMVIAY)**